# Database import error..<!— PMA-SQL-ERROR -->

Tags: mysql

I have a wordpress site, but when I import the database in my cpanel I found SQL error:

```
SQL query: Edit

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM skynines_advicementor

MySQL said: Documentation

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

Error
SQL query at line 1
```

I can't find solution of this error.

Comment: Maybe try "show tables from <database_name>"

Comment: What are you trying to import into which database? What is the query on line 1?

Comment: Voting to close, this has been abandoned.